# escaping {} brackets in triple quote Python strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, formatting

how can you format a string of this form in Python 3?

```
'''{name}{{name}}'''.format(name="bob")
```

the desired output is: `bob{bob}`, but the above gives: `bob{name}`.

one solution is to add another argument to `format`:

```
'''{name1}{name2}'''.format(name1="bob", name2="{bob}")
```

but this is excessive. is there a way to properly escape `{` such that inner `{x}` can still be interpolated and one can only pass a single `name` to `format`?

Comment: Err, did you try `'''{name}{{{name}}}'''.format(name="bob")`?

Comment: note: this would be the same with single-quote strings as well, the whole point of `{{` / `}}` is to escape `{` / `}` so it would be ignored by `.format()` and be taken as a literal char

Answer (score 5):

Add one more level of `{}`:

```
'''{name}{{{name}}}'''.format(name="bob")
```

which outputs:

```
bob{bob}
```